# Replace rows in a numpy 2d array with rows from another 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2d arrays, let's call them *img* ***(m * n)*** and *means* ***(k * n)***, and a list, let's call this clusters ***(m, )***. I'd like to replace rows in the *img* array with rows from the *means* array where I select the row from the *means* array based on the value in the *clusters* list. For example:

Suppose, *img*

```
img = np.array([[0.40784314, 0.48627451, 0.52549022],
                [0.05490196, 0.1254902, 0.2]]) # This will be a (m * n) array
```

And, *means*

```
means = np.array([[0.80551694, 0.69010299, 0.17438512],
                 [0.33569541, 0.45309059, 0.52275014]]) # (k * n) array
```

And, *clusters list*

```
clusters = [1, 0] # list of length m
```

The **Desired output** is

```
[[0.33569541 0.45309059 0.52275014]
 [0.80551694 0.69010299 0.17438512]] # This should be a (m * n) array, same as img above
```

Notice that the first row has been replaced with the second row from the means array because cluster[0] == 1 and second row has been replaced with the first row from the means array because cluster[1] == 0 and so on so forth.

I am able to do this using the following line of code, but I was wondering if there is any faster way of doing this, if any.

```
np.array([means[i] for i in clusters])
```

Comment: What does the `img` array have to do with the question? Your example doesn't seem to reflect your stated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```py
>>> means[clusters]
array([[0.33569541, 0.45309059, 0.52275014],
       [0.80551694, 0.69010299, 0.17438512]])
```